# Elementor Custom Icons not showing

Tags: elementor

I want to use the custom icons for Elementor's icon list. I used Icomoon to generate and download the icons. After I created the custom icons using elementor, they didn't show up in the Elementor editor. When opening the console, I found the following errors:

/wp-content/uploads/elementor/custom-icons/custom-icon-5/e_icons.js
[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 22ms]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `/wp-content/uploads/elementor/custom-icons/{icons-name}/` and clear that folder. For some reason when you delete icons in elementor, they are not deleted in that particular folder so they clash or something like that.